# Where is webapi.xsd located

Tags: api, rest-api, webapi

I have been trying to access a REST API end point that results in a `404 Not Found`. I have come across documentation that explains the endpoints have to be configured in the `webapi.xsd` file. I have looked in all the directories under the ISS installation and can't find the file.

The documentation says "By default, this file is in `app/code/<VENDOR>/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd`." but this directory doesn't exist.

Under `app/code` I only have "community" and "core"? Where is this file?

HELP!

Comment: I think you are reading M2 documentation and you are using M1

Comment: It is available here `route/vendor/magento/module-webapi/webapi.xsd` you need to add it in your xml file as follows 

`<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">`

Comment: I am discovered in the last hour I am on version 1.9.2.6 and the documentation I have been looking at is 2.1 I assume this is what you mean, which makes sense now. Do you know if its possible to add the "V1/integration/admin/token" REST call into the 1.9.2.6 setup. I want to use the REST API, so need to obtain an access token but wont be able to have the user entered their Magento admin username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I am discovered in the last hour I am on version 1.9.2.6 and the documentation I have been looking at is 2.1 I assume this is what you mean, which makes sense now. Do you know if its possible to add the "V1/integration/admin/token" REST call into the 1.9.2.6 setup. I want to use the REST API, so need to obtain an access token but wont be able to have the user entered their Magento admin username and password.